# Migrating style properties to separated .css file

Tags: javascript, html, css, optimization, stylesheet

Dear community members,

I need to put all:

```
    style="display:none"
```

from all rows with:

```
    <p class="text" style="display:none">
```

to the following stylesheet:

```
    style.css
```

on the    http://berdyanskaya56.ru/index.html.

Notable is that If I move

```
    "display:none"
```

to

```
    .text
```

in

```
    style.css
```

than the descriptive titles don't change respectively to pictures sliding (i.e., use arrow on both sides of the website screen) on the page.

For final clarification:

I need to remove all

```
    style="display:none"
```

from

```
    <p class="text" style="display:none">
```

to

```
    .text
```

at

```
    style.css.
```

This will substantially help me to clean up the code on the website. After changes are made the `<p>` tags in html page will look like:

```
    <p class="text">
```

If it requires further clarification, just post your comments below this post.

Thank you very much for your help in advance!

UPD: It will require also changing the function controlling display:none in JS. If you can help me with it, just post it below :-)!

Comment: The `display: none` looks like it's being controlled in the javascript. You'd have to dig into the javascript and remove the function controlling it, but of course you'd lose the sliding effect on the text. It's actually pretty minimal and functional as is.

Comment: Than you so much sir!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   /* style.css */
   /* set all `p` elements having `class` `"text"` 
      `display` property to `none`
   */
   p.text {
      display:none;
   }
```

Comment: @RuslanSeletskiy _"Seems it doesn't work at all."_ Can create stacksnippets , jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Comment: Yeah I see that it works in your case but not in mine :-( . Maybe it could be related to the specifics of local JS scripts of the website. Could it?

Comment: _"Yeah I see that it works in your case but not in mine :-( . Maybe it could be related to the specifics of local JS scripts of the website. Could it?"_ Not certain ? Try including all `js` , `css` , `html` at plnkr link to create Minimal Complete Verifiable Example http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to demonstrate

Answer (score 0):

Just make familiar yourself with basics of CSS.
In your case you've already set a class "text" to all your relevant objects.

Your CSS-File will contain something like

```
.text {
    display: none;
}
```

Edit:

You need also to link the CSS-file to your document inside the head-tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css" />
```

Here are some basics: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp

To change the text, you must add some javascript to your arrows setting the display-properties in the right way:

```
document.getElementById("<the id of the current text>").display = "none";
document.getElementById("<the id of the next text>").display = "inline";
```

For more information about manipulating CSS through JS, look here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp

Comment: Yes sir, I tried this option but the text doesn't change in respect to pictures slider.